# Как уменьшить размер текста в <a> елементе

Tags: html, css

Хочу уменьшить размер текста вот этих вот кнопок

Напишите код который уменьшит размер текста в  элементах
[image: Вот эти кнопки]

Вот код отвечающий за это:

```css
.person_description {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 1%;
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.person_description h3 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.person_description p {
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.person_links {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 80%;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.person_links a {

padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 3%;
background-color: #6e006e;
border-radius: 16px;
    font-size: px;

}


.person_links a:hover {
    background-color: #610061;
}
```

```html
    <div class="about_person">

        <div class="person_title">
            <h2 class="personName">Alexandr Kostylev</h2>
            <p class="personNickname">s1mple</p>
        </div>

        <div class="person_info">

            <img class="personImg" src="s1mple.jpg" alt="">

            <div class="person_description">
                <h3>About s1mple:</h3>
                <p>s1mple is a steamer and top1 HLTV and also he is the most popular cs:go player in the world</p>
                <p>Age: 25 years</p>
                <p>Team: Natus Vincere</p>
                <p>Role: AWP</p>

                

            </div>

            <div class="person_links">
                <a href="https://www.hltv.org/stats/players/7998/s1mple">HLTV</a>
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLyVaqx9Pezekijg0IF7NYA">YouTube</a>
                <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/officials1mple/">Steam</a>
            </div>
```

Пробовал `font-size` сделать поменьше тогда и сами кнопки делаются меньше а мне нужно чтобы только текст кнопок был меньше

Comment: Уменьшая `font-size` можно увеличивать `padding`. Размер сохранится...

Comment: Да ты гений!
Как я сам до этого не додумался  

Спасибо тебе большое
Я почти весь день над этим думал

Answer (score -1):

Уменьшая `font-size` можно увеличивать `padding`. Размер сохранится...
Автор ответа:@ksa

Comment: Стоило опубликовать ответ как общий, в любом случае ответ низкокачественный. Обязательно нужно писать исчерпывающие ответы. Допустим вы можете написать почему так происходит.

Comment: Та друг это ответ и он мне помог если мне помог - поможет и другим

Comment: Также если тебе хочется исправь если ты модер или если ты обычный пользователь то просто дополни тем чем считаешь нужным

Comment: А то что ты написал это мало пользы несёт - гараздо больше ответ автора @ksa

Comment: Ответ вы таки не исправили, ставлю минус. `Та друг это ответ и он мне помог если мне помог - поможет и другим`, ключевое слово - "может", если ответ непонятный или мало понятный, значит он не несёт пользы, [из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): `Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию.`.

Comment: `Также если тебе хочется исправь если ты модер или если ты обычный пользователь то просто дополни тем чем считаешь нужным` - то что нужно ответу, должно быть у него по умолчанию, правки призваны исправлять только недоработки.

Comment: `А то что ты написал это мало пользы несёт - гараздо больше ответ автора @ksa`, без спорно, тот комментарий, что написал @ksa полезен. Но он не тянет на уровень ответа, поэтому я попросил дополнить ваш ответ деталями.

Comment: Простите, но больше дискуссию с вами я продолжать не намерен. Тех комментариев что я написал должно быть достаточно, чтобы понять что не так с ответом.